# Information regarding License and available functionalities

Tags: community, customer-community, licenses, customer-community-plus

Can anyone tell me weather Reports and Dashboards are only available to customer community plus license User?
Can these feature be available to customer community license user also?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommended to go through [Communities User Licenses doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0) to get all information what you need.

> Can anyone tell me weather Reports and Dashboards are only available
>   to customer community plus license User?

**yes, and Partner Community Licenses Users also can vi**ew

> Can these feature be available to customer community license user
>   also?

**NO**

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to standard reporting, community plus and partner licences would be what you're limited to. If you're using Einstein Analytics in your Primary Salesforce Org, you'd be able to purchase licenses for users to view Einstein reports and Dashboards in your communities at a separate cost. That's the only way I can think of to get reporting (view only) in your Customer Community. Beyond that, the rest is the standard reports and dashboards available from the App Exchange which as I recall, are only visible inside your org or by your power users, which report on statistics in the community.